# append '[ ]' to a json string C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using D3 radar chart to draw a chart using json generated in a json file.
The frormat that i require is :

```
 [
    [
      {"Key": "Collaboration", "value": 0.22},
      {"Key": "People", "value": 0.41},
      {"Key": "Program/Project Complexity", "value": 0.26},
      {"Key": "Process", "value": 0.18},
      {"Key": "Tools", "value": 0.18}
    ]
]
```

However when i convert my list<> to json using Newtonsoft i get this format:

```
[
  {"Key": "Collaboration\r\n", "Value": 0.22},
  {"Key": "People\r\n","Value": 0.41},
  {"Key": "Program/Project Complexity\r\n","Value": 0.26},
  {"Key": "Process\r\n","Value": 0.18},
  {"Key": "Tools\r\n","Value": 0.18}
]
```

Here is my code to convert and write json to a file:

```
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(consolidatedData);
string path = Server.MapPath("~/JSON_Results/");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "data.json", jsonResult);
```

NOTE: consolidatedData in a key value list

Is there a way to append '[ ]' to my json file?? If not please suggest an alternative.

Comment: Isn't that JSON a `List<List<T>>`?

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is returning a string so you can just do `string.Concat("[", jsonResult, "]")`

Comment: as @CamiloTerevinto states, looks like the JSON is representing a list of lists, not a single flat list.  perhaps a `List<List<KeyValuePair>>` or a `List<Dictionary<string, decimal>>`?

Comment: As an alternative, you could leave the serialization alone, then in the Javascript side when adding this to the D3 chart you could create an array and `.push()` this object into that, then pass that onto D3.  I think this is because the D3 chart stuff allows you to pass multiple series into the list of data but you're only passing one)

Comment: @mirg Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: Actually your question is kind of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable replies. My problem is sorted.

Comment: @SDR Your problem was sorted in very limited way. There are several questions, why you need to do that? You are writing to some file and another program/method reading that file (json) and doing something, but if you wrote that part, maybe you need to change it's reading part, to read just `IEnumerable<T>`? Or maybe you can't write that way, and should use another object? Too many "maybe"s.

Comment: @SeM actually i am capturing survey results in a key value pair and convert it to a json and write it to a json file so that d3.js can read that data and populate the graph.
My modification for d3.js map() takes array as an argument. For that i needed to append '[ ]'

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(consolidatedData);
var newList = new List<string>(new string[] {jsonResult});
var newResult =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newList);
string path = Server.MapPath("~/JSON_Results/");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "data.json", newResult);
```